# Como resolver esses erros de libpng no pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Esses erros são mostrados quando eu encerro o jogo:

**libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile**
**libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB**

Esses erros acontecem porque estou utilizando isso:

```
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("imagens/truco.png"))
```

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Você poderia incluir o código completo na pergunta ? Poderia fornecer a imagem .png ? Consegue reproduzir/isolar os erros em um exemplo mínimo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso **não** são erros, são *"avisos"* (warning) e o problema talvez seja na imagem que esteja com o **"perfil de cores"** (ICC profile) da imagem e provavelmente não afeta a sua aplicação, você pode até ignorar esses avisos se desejar, ou seja não é um problema no seu código.

O que você talvez possa resolver facilmente usando um programa de desenho para corrigir **"a imagem"** com problema, como por exemplo GIMP ou Photoshop.

Existe uma solução online como esta: http://tinypng.com - que além de provavelmente resolver esses "avisos" ainda irá reduzir o tamanho das imagens tornando seu programa mais leve em diferentes sentidos.

Também existe o https://pmt.sourceforge.io/pngcrush/ (download https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmt/files/pngcrush-executables/) que é capaz de remover os perfis de cores inválidos, depois de instalado usando este comando:

```
pngcrush -ow -rem allb -reduce file.png
```

Comment: Eu não conhecia essa ferramenta, resolveu o problema.

Comment: @MatheusSilvaPinto que bom, obrigado pelo reconhecimento.

Answer (score 3):

Isso se trata de um *warning* emitido pela `libpng`. Significa que o arquivo de imagem `PNG` que você está usando possui [*chunks iCCP* inválidos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile).

Para remover os *chunks* inválidos de uma imagem `PNG`, você pode usar o utilitário [`convert`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/convert) da biblioteca [`ImageMagick`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) passando o argumento [`-strip`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip) na linha de comando:

```
$ convert icone.png -strip icone_ok.png
```

Assumindo que você tenha um arquivo de imagem, no formato `PNG`, com dimensões de `400x400`, chamado `icone.png`:

[image: SOpt]

Segue um programa capaz de carregar a imagem acima por meio da função `pygame.image.load()` e depois utilizá-la como o icone da janela criada por meio da função `pygame.display.set_icon()` sem nenhum tipo de erro ou *warning*:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

icon = pygame.image.load('icone.png')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption('FooBar')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen.blit( icon, (50,50))

clk = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True;

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False;
    pygame.display.update()
    clk.tick(25);

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Exemplo sendo testado em uma área de trabalho `Linux/GNOME`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]