# Capturar python libpng warning

Tags: python, opencv

Estou tentando tratar um enorme número de imagens com `opencv` em python

A grande maioria será desprezada, então gostaria de capturar as mensagens de warning do opencv para poder tratar/desprezar essas imagens.

Já tentei `warnings`, `sys.stderr` mas os warnings continuam aparecendo e não consigo capturar/tratar.

São poucas as imagens com warnigs. Mas quer tratar.

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

um pequeno exemplo :

```
import cv2

import warnings


warnings.filterwarnings("error")


try:

    cv2.imread('/dados/dev/google/google/downloads/amazan/20.amazan.png')

    print('Imagem lida')

except Exception as error_e:

    print(f"Erro/Warning : {error_e}")
```

Resultado :

> /usr/bin/python3.7 /dados/dev/google/lab/teste.py
>
> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>
> libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
>
> Imagem lida

Comment: Esses warning, não são tratados pela linguagem. São o resultado da aplicação de um perfil ICC não padrão. Então o que deve fazer é remover com um software de edição gráfica o perfil ICC problemático. Se for ambiente Linux use o ImageMagick para pós-processar imagens pois ele corrige vários bugs que os editores gráficos deixam ou ignoram nas imagens.

Comment: São milhões de imagens, só queria saber quais tem esse warning para desprezar. para que não cheguem na próxima fase ainda com warning. É um processo automático que vai rodar em background, sem interação humana. Mas já tenho mais informação para continuar pesquisando. Muito obrigado. Valeu.

Comment: Augusto não entendi o motivo de ter votado no fechamento. A pergunta continuou sem resposta. Pode me explicar o porque?

Comment: A resposta é que esses warnings não são tratados pela linguagem e você tem que, fora da linguagem, usar um software de processamento para normalizar as imagens. Conceito que foge ao escopo das linguagens de programação.

Comment: Quer dizer que se eu fizer um programa que usa imagens, devo deixar esses warnings aparecerem para o usuário final? Afinal as imagens não serão sempre minhas, alguém pode usar isso. Não acredito que não exista uma maneira de reconhecer esse warning. mesmo que eu não o trate. Mas deixar ir para a tela não faz sentido.

Comment: Só dar uma olhada [Pesquisa Google como suprimir os warnings da libpng](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNRveM0C3DQFjOEQol2JmjS5Vxm26w%3A1575926531993&ei=A7vuXZSlPLrC5OUP6dOTkAw&q=suppress+libpng+warning&oq=libpng+supre&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i22i10i30.8891.11771..14167...0.2..0.327.1482.2-5j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0j0i67j0i203j0i22i30.sNalN1BEswE). Não há a possibilidade de supressão, esse é preço a se pagar por software free. Se quer um maior controle escreva a sua própria biblioteca gráfica ou modifique a libpng para se adequar a suas finalidades.

Comment: Consegui ajuda e a solução no stack overflow internacional. Ainda não acho que era motivo para fechar minha pergunta, afinal achei uma solução dentro do meu código.
mas ... tudo bem, aprendi mais um pouco.
Se tiver interesse:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257111/how-to-identify-a-libpng-warning-in-python

Comment: Mas foi dito a mesma coisa que aqui transcrição dos comentários: "Esses erros provavelmente vêm da biblioteca C, e nada na camada python; portanto, o uso de warnings e sys.stderr não será detectado (como você experimentou). A única coisa que vem à mente neste momento é redirecionar o STDERR do processo quando seu script é chamado. Provavelmente não é ideal para um script que você deseja fornecer a outros usuários. -  Gordon Bean 1 hora atrás" .....

Comment: "Você pode tentar ler uma imagem como binário direto (não decodificá-la como PNG) e procurar a string iCCPnela. Ignore o arquivo, se presente. -  Mark Setchell 1 hora atrás

Os arquivos PNG são muito modulares, então você também pode editar esse pedaço do arquivo e carregá-lo com o OpenCV. Tente pesquisar usando apenas grepalguns arquivos para ver se ele identifica os problemáticos e não muitos perfeitamente felizes corretamente"

Comment: Se você está insatisfeito com o fechamento da pergunta. Faça uma reclamação no [Stack Oerflow META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Como já respondi, [warnings não são erros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252435/3635), as imagens provavelmente estão mesmo com problemas no perfil de cores, mas isso não afeta diretamente (geralmente) o que irá fazer com a imagem, e como disse, pode tentar usar o [`pngcrush`](https://pmt.sourceforge.io/pngcrush/) com comando linha nas imagens da pasta toda (se for de fatos todas PNG com problema), exemplo:

```
find -f . png | while read filename; do pngcrush -ow -rem allb -reduce "{$filename}"; done
```

Agora suprimir o erro não vai resolver o problema, concorda?

Quero deixar claro que esses warnings não são gerados "totalmente" pelo openCV, mas sim do libpng, portanto pode ser que nem seja um warning ao nível do script mesmo, pode ser que seja apenas um output normal do libpng e realmente você não vai ter controle algum sobre isto e suprimir os warnings não será a mesma coisa que usar um `try/except` para obter ele em uma exceção.

Comment: Guilherme, estou chegando realmente a conclusão que não vou ter controle sobre isso mesmo e você tem razão, suprimir não é a solucão.
O que eu realmente queria era identificar esses warnings dentro do meu programa, mas não consegui.

Mas muito obrigado.

Comment: Não desmerecendo o seu comando mas com imagemagick é mais fácil basta fazer `mogrify *.png` que ele conserta todos os arquivos duma pasta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques se tiver instalado e o tal `mogrify` e realmente ele mapear "RECURSIVAMENTE" ai ajudaria, mas são programas diferentes, até aonde parece. ps: o comando `find` e o uso do pipe (`|`) ou do `while` são comandos de sistemas unix-like, justamente para trabalhar com arquivos, seja recursivamente ou em um level combinando com outros programas, o que muitas vezes é uma mão na roda :)